# Source Control in Xcode, SVN

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, svn

I'm new to the idea of source control and SVN.  We have our code on one of our consultant companies' servers.  If I access the code from my home iMac, is there any possibility of viruses or other bad things reaching my computer?  Sorry for the naive question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure you trust the other folks contributing to the SVN repository. If there is an infected file checked into the repository and you download it, then yes, you would at risk. Treat these files the same as if the other contributors handed you a disk with the files on it.

The process of just using SVN should not be a significant risk. It's the files you download from it that could be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In short, **no, you're probably safe**.

The process of checking things in and out of svn is almost certainly not going to add any new risks to your machine.

You might want to make sure that you're using an encrypted connection, though, as good practice and to ensure coherence of the data. In other words, make sure you're connecting to the repository over SSH.